# How to use different set of text sizes in android?

Tags: android, android-resources, android-fonts

In my app, i need to keep an action to change the font size. I am trying to keep three set of values for text sizes (small,medium and large). How should i switch between them? My idea is to use one set of font resource at a time.

**For more clarification:**

In Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar, to shift between night mode on and off in  i can call

```
 AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
```

and

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
```

Here, each will use different set of resource values for night mode on and off. I am looking for somewhat such a method to shift between different font sizes. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's something like that built into the operating system. If you go to *Settings > Accessibility* you'll find a *Large text* toggle or a slider to make text bigger (depending on phone). This will work in your app as long as you use `sp` for your font sizes (for example `android:textSize="16sp"`).

If you're going to use that, you'll have to remember that the setting is in the phone settings, I don't think there's a way for you to change it from your app. And it applies to all the apps, not just to yours, so everything in the system would get bigger. Which might be not what you require.

Otherwise you can try to do this manually in your app. One way would be to create three themes that have your different font sizes. Then you would set an appropriate theme on the context in your `Activity.onCreate()` based the setting you saved somewhere (in `SharedPreference` for example).

But I don't think you can just keep different font sizes in different resource subdirectories. The [list of resource qualifiers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) is predefined and I don't think there's something for switching font sizes in there.

Comment: Using sharedpref  it will make me to check the preferences each time. Anyway if there is no other option, then i ll go for that. Thanks.

Comment: @HariKrishnan, I have same scenario for my app, I can not find any global solution , is there any other solutions other than style xml. Any help will be appreciated.